# Remove account from Google Account chooser

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-multi-login

I've looked at several forums [like this one](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/pZ__WBz0kko/aKbYmZapercJ) and [this one](http://gmail-tips.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-sign-in-page.html) but since Google changes their interface every couple days, they're all wrong.

Here's what my sign in page looks like today and I can't remove any of the accounts from the list:

First I go to gmail.com and get this:

[image]

Then I click *Sign in with a different account* and get this:

[image]

Comment: There should be "remove account" on the sign-in page next to "add account". Where is this screenshot from? A sign in page or an account page?

Comment: @Raystafarian I updated the question to show how I got there

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you have any extensions on it? It seems like what you should see is being removed or blocked.

Comment: @Raystafarian Google Chrome, Windows 7 64b, no extensions

Comment: I see the same as the OP. There was no Remove account button but it appeared when I logged out of one of the Google accounts that I was logged into.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make sure you go to google.com not google.ext (where ext is from your country).

From there log out from all listed accounts, and on the login windows, choose log in with other account.

This should give you this:

[image]

If you don't see the above at this point even, clear your browsercache, temporary internet files and cookies. Then try again.

Comment: I'm in the US going to google.com. I logged in and out and remove was there. I'm highly perturbed that this worked. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: My guess is that the view without "remove" is when an application requested for logging through your Google account.

Comment: From the "Remove" screen, be careful to click "Done" when you're finished. Clicking anywhere on the account (not just on the "X") removes that account, and you need to add the account again.

Comment: It's the logging out that is the trick.

Comment: Terrible UI design by Google... what a convoluted way to even get to this screen!

Comment: To clarify, when you have multiple accounts in the list, you must sign out of ALL accounts for the "Remove" button to show up. That took me a while to figure out.

Comment: @BrianMoeskau thanks for the inforation. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Since I do not have reputation I could not post the answer. But it is as easy as: 1) in Google Chrome go to google.com; 2) click in the top-right icon of your picture and press "add account" 3) press F12; 4) Click in Application; 5) select one of the options on the left Cookies and search by "account chooser" name in the table on the right. 6) Delete that occurrence. 

That's it.

Comment: Looks like if you go to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin there is a "Remove" button at the bottom now

Answer (score 16):

You can make the Remove account button appear by logging out of one of the Google accounts that you are logged into.

Comment: You have to log out of ALL accounts, not just one of them.

Comment: was able to make it appear by logging out of only one account

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable the entire system, not just remove a particular account, go to this page

https://www.accountchooser.com/learnmore.html

Scroll down until you see a button that says “Disable Account Chooser”. After you click it, Gmail won't remember the accounts that have logged in (except if your browser fills in fields, but that's another mechanism). Basically, you are back where you were before Google "improved" Gmail with this chooser thing.

To be fair, it's a useful feature for many cases, but terrible for shared computers.

Comment: I wanted this to work, and I assume it did once, but no more.

Comment: It still works for me... maybe try disabling and re-enabling? I'm using Firefox v 56.0

Comment: Still works for me. Thanks